# VB.Net: prevent Narrowing Conversion on For Each

Tags: vb.net

### *SHORT ANSWEAR*: there is no way to prevent this

Maybe this question is duplicated, but I didnt find any solutions because I dont know what words should I search for:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Fruit
    '... stuff
End Class

Public Class Apple
    Inherits Fruit
    '... stuff
End Class

Public Class FruitCart

    Private _fruits As New List(Of Fruit)

    Public Function GetFirstApple() As Apple
        Return Me._fruits(0) '... <-- Option Strict error
    End Function

    Public Function GetApples() As List(Of Apple)
        Dim result As New List(Of Apple)
        For Each A As Apple In Me._fruits '... Why no error?
            result.Add(A)
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

End Class
```

The method GetFirstApple() gives me a compile error. This is the behavior I want.
The method GetApples() dont give me a compile error, leading to run-time error.

Why the compiler allows the casting on the For Each, even with Option Strict On?
I want the compiler to give me a compile error on the GetApples() method.

Comment: Why haven’t you included the text of the specific errors you’re seeing? [ask]

Comment: Is not it obvious? I want a compile error like "Not every fruit is an apple".

Comment: Can't have it, as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement) in the "Narrowing conversions" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it out. There is no way to prevent this, as documented on the "Narrowing conversions" on the For Each page: [For Each documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement)

[image]